# Xcode Server - pending integration, "There are 0 integrations ahead of it in the queue"

Tags: xcode, xcode-server

I try to perform integration for my project, but there is permanent info:

[image]

It is not about to start integrate. If I cancel integration and start it again, the same info appears. What to do to make it working?

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way to do this is to run this command from the Terminal on a machine that is running the bot:

```
sudo xcrun xcscontrol --restart
```

Note, you want to pass `--restart` and **not** `--reset`. One just restarts the server, and is usually enough to get the integrations going again. the `--reset` command will reset the Xcode server and you'll have to create all your bots again.

Further information can be found from the built in help with:

```
sudo xcrun xcscontrol --help
```

Comment: I have this same problem with every build I try on a particular server and --restart never fixes it.  Any logs available to see why the build is hanging?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and restarting the run did not work for me.

So I deleted the "DerivedData" folder.

[image]

After that, the message changed to something of the kind "The mac server is not logged in the   account".
I just logged out and logged back in and everything was working fine.

I hope that this helps some people with the same issue.